# Access custom cell properties in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. I want to access the cells properties i.e. a `UILabel` etc. I tried inserting the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategorieCell *customCell = (CategorieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return ...
}
```

When I run the app, it crashed without giving me error details. The problem is with the new customCell I'm creating. Is there another way I can access the `customCell.m` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the crash, please note that you are using cellForRowAtIndexPath: wich is a method from the UITableViewDatasource that you have to implement, this method calls heightForRowAtIndexPath by default, so it will become a recursive

I assume that you want your custom cell in this method in order to get the height from it. 
The best way to achieve this is write a class method on CategorieCell that gives you the height for a cell with certain data.

Other option is extract a method with the code to get the uitableviewcell for example

```
(CategorieCell*) categorieCellForIndex:(NSIndex)index selected:(BOOL)selected{
...
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the label will give a height of 0 because the label gets added only once the cell gets selected. though I didn't try it

Comment: Why not return conditionally a cell selected or not, you could save the state on the cell itself and therefore the height will depend on this

Answer (score 1):

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` should never be called `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The first one is called before the second one, and if you need to access to a label (for example to calculate the height of the text) you can normally init a cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static CategorieCell *cell;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width-tableView.contentInset.left-tableView.contentInset.right, cell.frame.size.height);
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    cell.label.text = myDatasourceText;

    CGFloat cellHeight = ....

    return cellHeight;
}
```

**NOTE 1:**
I used `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` supposing you are using Interface Builder, otherwise you need to use `alloc] initWithStyle:...]`;

**NOTE 2:**
As you see I'm setting the frame of the cell. This is needed because otherwise your cell will be `(320 x 44)` as default. You instead could be in `iPhone 6/6+ (i.e. screen width: 414)` or in an `iPad`, and you could need to calculate an height of a label according with his width and his text, and for this reason you need to set the frame of the cell.

**NOTE 3:**
I'm assuming you have a set of equal cell structure, and for this reason I'm using a `static` cell, so it will be **reused** without allocate other useless cells.

Comment: Actually I will be using diff cell heights. Also, Do I have to set a new frame for the cell?

Comment: Different height is ok, it is calculated `CGFloat cellHeight = ....`. I was talking about different TYPE of cell. But doesn't seems your case as looks like you have just `CategoryCell` so just 1type of cell. You have not to set any frame, it is set automatically you have just to return the height.

Answer (score 1):

Try to register your custom cell class like so:

`[self.tableView registerClass:[CategorieCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CategorieCell class]);`

and then in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` do something like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    CategorieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CategorieCell class)];

}
```

Comment: First off, at the first `NSStringFromClass` I tried what you did and no cells showed up, When I inserted `@"CategoriCell"` instead of `[CategorieCell class]` it worked. The problem is when I select a cell I made an `NSLog` of the height of the label, and it gave me 0

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, do you just want to know what the size of the label would eventually be?  If so just access the label, assign the test and calls `[label sizeToFit] `